# how to know which version of the compiler used to install a program from source among all versions of the that compiler

Tags: gcc, source-code, g++, source-packages

I installed a program via source code . To do that I **downloaded a gcc and g++ appropriate for that**. I use this command in order to install that

```
$ export CC=gcc-?? CXX=g++-?? && ./install
```

??=I do not remember

now I forget the version of those . Is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC writes a **.comment** section containing version info in the compiled object file.

You can try to dump **.comment** section from the binary to find the version string.

Use **objdump** and add **--section** to specify section name.

For example, if your compiled a program named **foo** in the source dir, you can run the following commands to get GCC's version info:

```
$ objdump -s --section .comment foo

sizeof:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 20285562 756e7475 2f4c696e  GCC: (Ubuntu/Lin
 0010 61726f20 342e362e 332d3175 62756e74  aro 4.6.3-1ubunt
 0020 75352920 342e362e 3300               u5) 4.6.3.
```

Then you know it's compiled with gcc 4.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Type `gcc -v` in terminal.

> Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
>   Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-java-awt=gtk --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
>   Thread model: posix
>   **gcc version 3.4.6** 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-3)

Comment: thanks for you help. but I have more than six gcc. also I downloaded another .deb gcc the problem is which gcc I use to install the that program